How can I display Custom Content Types (CCT) created with the JetEngine plugin in WPGraphQL?
The issue I'm facing is integrating Custom Content Types (CCT) created with the JetEngine plugin into WPGraphQL. Specifically, I need guidance on how to properly configure and query these CCTs within WPGraphQL so that I can effectively retrieve and display this custom data on my WordPress site. I have already set up CCTs using JetEngine but I am unsure of the necessary steps to make them accessible through WPGraphQL.
Please give me the solution for custom content types to show in graphql .

CCT slug : reviews ,
DB table name : wp_jet_cct_reviews ,
Fields :  _ID    name    country star    review_date feedback    label   link    logo    cct_author_id   cct_created cct_modified

